# Comparing values using == operator

Tags: c#

I have a static method which simply compares two values and returns the result

```
public class Calculator
{
    public static bool AreEqual(object value1, object value2)
    {
        return value1 == value2;
    }

}

 bool Equal = Calculator.AreEqual("a", "a"); // returns true
 bool Equal = Calculator.AreEqual(1, 1);    // returns false
```

Can someone please explain what is going on behind the scenes that produces the output described     above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runtime identifies your literal usages of `"a"` and retrieves the same reference to all those usages, resulting in one string object rather than two as you would expect.

Instead of using literals, try the following:

```
string A1 = new string(new char[] {'a'});
string A2 = new string(new char[] {'a'});

Calculator.AreEqual(A1, A2); // returns false
```

What you've presented here is known as string interning.
You can find more information in the [String.Intern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method page.